# Cell data cleanup in Excel with Apache POI(Extract only alphabets)

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have cell data which has some special characters such as `.>%/`, in addition to the English alphabet.

I am trying to remove all the characters one by one:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("MM_",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($AB$2," ",""),"%",""),",",""),">",""),"/",""),"(",""),")",""),"-","")))
```

All I want is to extract the alphabetic characters from it, but repeating `SUBSTITUTE` creates confusion.

Any thought on how can I extract the alphabets without repeating `SUBSTITUTE`?

Comment: Since you're using Apache POI, why not fetch the string contents of the cell, clean it up with Java code, then write the cleaned text back?

Comment: @Gagravarr Actually the final excel file should contain all these characters. But since these characters are not used(i.e., not allowed) in the formula so we need to remove them for the calculation purposes.

Comment: Can you provide some test data and tell us what is not working. I agree with @Gagravarr, why not clean your string using Java and use it in variable for calculation?